# If statement in Worksheet_Change not working with On Error Resume Next

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, worksheet-function

I pull river level data from the National Weather Service with Power Query.

I want to use VBA to automatically send me an email if the river level exceeds a certain level.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xRg = Intersect(Range("B2"), Target)
   If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 15 Then
      Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
   End If
End Sub
```

When the Power Query refreshes, it triggers the Worksheet_Change event. This sends an email regardless of cell B2's value. I'd like it to send an email only when the value exceeds 15.

I tried adding the following code to resolve the issue.

```vb
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <= 15 Then Exit Sub
```

The above code did stop the event from sending an email when the value does not exceed 15, but it also stopped the event from triggering when the Power Query is refreshed.
I need the Worksheet_Change event to fire whenever the Power Query refreshes.

If I resolve this issue, I'm hoping to add something to turn off the Worksheet_Change event to stop it from sending the email more than once.

Comment: Is there other Sub procedure acesses the varible `xRg`? Why do you use `Dim xRg As Range` as module-scope varible?  Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.

Comment: No, there aren't other Sub procedure accessing the variable xRg. I used the Dim statement as a module-scope variable because I copied the code from someone else to get started and edited it for my own purpose haha. I appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.
- If no other procedures (Sub/Function) access the variable `xRg`, consider moving the Dim statement into the `Worksheet_Change` event.
- If `Target` is a multiple-cell `Range`, `Target.Value` is equivalent to `Target.Cells(1).Value`. For example, if PQ updates `A2:K5`, then `Target.Value` is the content of cell `A2` instead of `B2`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Me.Range("B4") <> "Yes" Then Exit Sub ' switch of mailing
   Dim xRg As Range
   Set xRg = Intersect(Me.Range("B2"), Target)
   If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If IsNumeric(Me.Range("B2").Value) And Me.Range("B2").Value > 15 Then
      Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
   End If
End Sub
```

---

> Question: add a button or something like that to turn off the Worksheet_Change event and stop it from sending out the email more than once

- Add a ActiveX commandbutton on sheet (Sheet1)
- Add event code in `ThisWorkbook` module.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to DisableEvents"
End Sub
```

- Add event code in `Sheet1` module

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Application
        ' Update CommandButton1 caption
        Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Click to " & IIf(.EnableEvents, "EnableEvents", "DisableEvents")
        ' Switch setting
        .EnableEvents = Not .EnableEvents
        Me.Range("E1").Value = .EnableEvents  ' for demo
    End With
End Sub
' Demo event code
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "You select cell " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution for my code worked perfectly. I'm very new to VBA, so I copied a lot of my code from other people's codes. I appreciate your tips on what to avoid and where to place the Dim statements.

Comment: While you were adding the second part to your answer (regarding the turn on/off button), I went ahead and used what I learned from you to create a "Yes"/"No" dropdown for the email notification. I added an extra condition to the If statement (see below) and it actually works as a make-shift button.

If IsNumeric(Me.Range("B2").Value) And Me.Range("B2").Value > 15 And Me.Range("B4") = "Yes" Then

Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook

I'll definitely try out the button solution that you provided tomorrow! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's good.  If you insert `If Me.Range("B4") <> "Yes" Then Exit Sub` as the first code line of `Worksheet_Change`, it saves time when the events is disabled. See the updated answer.